# Postgres AWS EBS volume doesn't persist when updating service

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, aws-ebs, docker-aws

I deploy a service on a standard Docker for AWS stack (using this [template](https://editions-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/aws/stable/Docker.tmpl)).
I deploy using `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml pos` with this compose file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  postgres_vanilla:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: "cloudstor:aws"
    driver_opts:
      size: "6"
      ebstype: "gp2"
      backing: "relocatable"
```

I then change some data in the db and force an update of the service with `docker service update --force pos_postgres_vanilla`

Problem is that the data I change doesn't persist after the update.
I've noticed that postgres initdb script runs every time I update, so I assume it's related.

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that `cloudstor:aws` creates the volume with a `lost+found` under it, so when postgres starts it finds that the data directory isn't empty and complains about it. To fix that I changed the volume to be mounted one directory above the data directory, at `/var/lib/postgresql`, but that caused postgres to not find the PGVERSION file, which in turn caused it to run initdb every time the container starts (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L57).

So to work around it, instead of changing the volume to be mounted one directory above the data directory, I changed the data directory to be one level below the volume mount by overriding environment variable `PGDATA` (to something like `/var/lib/postgresql/data/db/`).